# Flash AS3 returning a value after Mouseclick

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I need help with returning a variable after a mouse click for some reason my code doesn't work

```
function LeftMercury(e:MouseEvent):Number
{
 var ldiameter:Number = 4800;
 return ldiameter;
}

trace(LeftMercury());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var ldiameter:Number=0;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,LeftMercury);
function LeftMercury(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    ldiameter=4800;
    trace(ldiameter);// OR
    trace(e.stageX); // Mouse Position
}
```

**you can be the solution ?**

Answer (score 1):

its hard to help when you simply state the problem and no background knowledge, but from a first glance, i see that calling LeftMercury() with no parameters, when the function expects one is bad. instead make the function set e to null when nothing is supplied, so if you call LeftMercury() with no parameters, the compiler just makes e equal to null by default, placing a MouseEvent in their will work too as it will override the default null value you have set:

```
function LeftMercury(e:MouseEvent=null):Number
{
 var ldiameter:Number = 4800;
 return ldiameter;
}

trace(LeftMercury());
```

This code is perfect, but if it still does not work, I can't help you. You'll have to update your question to provide more background and code for us.

Answer (score 0):

it should be a global variable to do that :

so declare it outside of the function

```
var ldiameter:Number;
function LeftMercury(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 ldiameter = 4800;
}

trace(ldiameter);
```

Comment: i tried this but NaN always come out instead of  4800 anyway to fix this?

Comment: NaN because the value haven't been added, may be because you haven't fired the listener ... your LeftMercury is a listener, since (e:MouseEvent) so be sure that you are firing the event and using the variable after doing so